# How to implement conditional euclidean clustering in ROS?

Tags: ros, pcl, object-detection, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am aware of the the conditional euclidean clustering is available on PCL [website](http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/conditional_euclidean_clustering.php#conditional-euclidean-clustering). But can someone please tell me how to implement this in ROS?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/225020/how-to-implement-conditional-euclidean-clustering-in-ros?/) by [blackmamba591](https://answers.ros.org/users/23981/blackmamba591/) on ROS Answers with karma: 38 on 2016-01-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Take a look at the [PCL Ros tutorials](http://wiki.ros.org/pcl/Tutorials). There is nothing special about PCL, it can be used as any third-party library.

You will get your potincloud messages in ROS as sensor_msgs::Pointcloud2. But in the tutorials they explain how to convert this to PCL pointcloud type:

```
pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ> cloud;
pcl::fromROSMsg (*input, cloud);
```

You can find more information about how to convert types [here](http://wiki.ros.org/pcl/Overview). Note that an awesome feature is what is explained at the end of [section 3.1](http://wiki.ros.org/pcl/Overview#Subscribing_to_different_point_cloud_message_types):

```
// Need to include the pcl ros utilities
#include "pcl_ros/point_cloud.h"

// callback signature, assuming your points are pcl::PointXYZRGB type:
void callback(const pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>::ConstPtr&);

// create a templated subscriber
ros::Subscriber sub = nh.subscribe<pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB> > (topic, queue_size, callback);
```

That is, ROS includes some hooks so that you can subscribe directly to the PCL pointcloud type and thus you do not need to carry out any conversion.

---

Originally posted by [Javier V. Gómez](https://answers.ros.org/users/5464/javier-v.-g%C3%B3mez/) with karma: 1305 on 2016-01-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [blackmamba591](https://answers.ros.org/users/23981/blackmamba591/) on 2016-01-26**:
Thanks a lot, I implemented the SAC segmentation with some changes, and it works, I will give it a try. Thanks for your response Javier

**Comment by [Javier V. Gómez](https://answers.ros.org/users/5464/javier-v.-g%C3%B3mez/) on 2016-01-26**:
I am happy that helped :)